# How can I adjust the height of \cong, \simeq and = to be the same?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, relation-symbols

Alright, if you write the three symbols

```
\cong \simeq =
```

next to each other (say you are proving in a line that two things are equivalent but there are some equalities and isomorphisms around) the heights do not match and it looks ugly. I would like that the bottom horizontal line in each one is at the same height.

I have partially solved it, but I am not satisfied. The following minimal example makes `\cong` and `\simeq` approximately at the same height.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\let\oldsimeq\simeq
\renewcommand{\simeq}{\mathrel{\raisebox{.456mm}{$\oldsimeq$}}}

\begin{document}

{\huge \[=\cong\simeq\cong=\simeq=\cong\simeq\cong=\]}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make them *exactly* at the same height? Maybe there is a clever way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The amount of raising should depend on some font parameter; by visual inspection, I found that 40% of `\fontdimen22` related to the current style is good. For aligning `\cong`, remove the .5pt lowering.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% fix \simeq
% (1) save a copy of it
\mathchardef\latex@simeq\simeq
% (2) undefine \simeq
\let\simeq\relax
% (3) redefine it
\DeclareRobustCommand{\simeq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\new@simeq\relax}}
\newcommand{\new@simeq}[2]{%
  \raisebox{\simeq@raise{#1}}{$\m@th#1\latex@simeq$}%
}
% (4) the helper command
\newcommand{\simeq@raise}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle .4\fontdimen22\textfont2\fi
  \ifx#1\textstyle .4\fontdimen22\textfont2\fi
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle .4\fontdimen22\scriptfont2\fi
  \ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle .4\fontdimen22\scriptscriptfont2\fi
}

% fix \cong
\patchcmd{\@vereq}{.5}{0}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[=\cong\simeq_{=\cong\simeq}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe the script size should be raised a bit up, change `\scriptstyle .4\fontdimen` into `\scriptstyle .45\fontdimen`

Comment: in the process, you've managed to change the shape of the `\cong`.  in the subscript, the `\sim` component is too close to the top bar of the equals.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Blame Knuth for that

Comment: Thanks egreg, It worked fine! although only for me to realise that the bar under `\simeq` is different from the ones of `=` and `\cong` I changed the .4 distance for .425 looks slightly better.

Also, why does the fix for `\cong` doesn't involve the symbol `\cong` at all?

Comment: @RamónAbudAlcalá The `\cong` symbol is built from `=` and `\sim`; the patch removes its lowering.